# Converting 2008 ssis to 2019 - package configuration not working in debug

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]I have been using XML config files for a long time. I know there are thousands of post on this. Most are not about SSIS VS2019. The ones that I found that do stop at how to setup packages. None explain what happens if it doesn't work.  Upgraded all my packages from SSIS 2008 to 2019. Everything converts good except scripts. I setup my package configuration and try to run in debug it is still using the values in the package not the config file. I Also tried running them in Server Agent with the same results. Not sure where I went wrong or if its a SSIS BI issue. Please help, Thank you.

1. Add a existing 2008 package to my project
2. Had to rewrite all the scripts by copping the code. Create a new Script task\component. Paste the code in the new script close the window. Ran the project on my local DB. Everything worked.
3. Click on the packages background and then in the properties window open Configurations collection selected enable configurations.
4. Add a new configuration. Select values for Initial Catalog, Server Name, StartupDir, InputDir, ArchiveDir. Now points to Dev server and input directories.
5. Save the configuration.
6. In the package, I can now right click on the back screen and see Package Configurations as a selection. I open it and package configuration's is enabled and the file is visible.
7. Close the configuration put a breakpoint in the package.
8. Click Start, Check the variables in the locals window. They do not have the configured values.
9. If i let it run it updates my local db not the DEV one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to change the protection level to DontSaveSensitive and changing the target version to 2019. My local server is 2016 so not sure why DEV and Prod are 2019 so if I can debug on 2016 with a 2019 target I'm good with that.
Warning for anyone trying this. After doing this I received a bunch of errors when I tried to open packages with scripts. I had to open the script and close it to rebuild. Then it worked and the massage went away.

[image: Error messages]

And before I forget there's this annoying little message. I just ignored it.

[image: Asked me to delete SSIS extensions]

Answer (score -2):

Please try to change SSIS Project/Package(s) **ProtectionLevel** setting to DontSaveSensitive.

Starting from SSIS 2012 onwards the preferred way is to use Project/Package level parameters instead of XML config files.

Comment: What did you get started there.,1LOL. Now it wants me to change all 75 package security to DontSaveSensitive oh well here I go.

Comment: @WIlliamBurke, otherwise, the connection strings are saved in the SSIS packages themself. And SSIS will not use your configurations.

Comment: Thank you, I see where that would make a difference. I'm going to mark this as answered but I am not sure what worked. I did two things Made the changes you suggested and changed the Target  Version to 2019. A lot of posts are saying 2019 debugging is not working with other target version. I tried it just changing the protection level by itself and it didn't look like it worked.

Comment: @WIlliamBurke, if your SSIS run-time environment on a server is SQL Server/SSIS 2019, you need to change the TargetVersion setting in VS as you did.